# Laravel: Authentication and Roledependent include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

First Laravel Project.
I want to achieve this logic in authentication:

```
Check if user logged in
 - If no: go to log in screen (views/auth.login)
 - If yes: check his role
    - if admin: Load admin navbar
    - if user: Load user navbar
```

For Login I want to use login.blade.php and for "index" I want to use index.blade.php

And in layouts.master's body I have a section with "nav" class and in this section I want to include an admin or user menu what depends of user role.

What's the best method?

Comment: Show your efforts..

Comment: The best method would be convert this `pseudo code` into `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are countless of authentication tutorials online. Just google it. YOu will find something. Then find a way to identify admin; by role_id, or simply with a property like `isAdmin = true`.

In the User model, define a function `isAdmin()` that returns true or false according to some verifications.

In your view

```
@if( Auth::user()->isAdmin())
    @include('inludes.nav.admin')
@else 
    @include('inludes.nav.user')
@endif
```

Example of tutorial for role based authentication: http://alexsears.com/article/adding-roles-to-laravel-users/

If you follow his tutorial, in the view you do

```
@if( $user->hasRole('admin') )  //or something similar
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect to login page is already there.
In your view you can check the role and load the correct bar.